# What are the (most brilliant) Use Cases (=Apps) that have been developed with Stackoverflow API?

Tags: discussion, api, stack-overflow

I would be very much thankfull to hear some good use cases (=applications) that have been developed with the Stackoverflow API. It does not matter if this is a web application, an mobile phone app, or legacy integration in an existing product.

I am very much happy with what stackoverflow does and I am wondering if there are any good usecaes how to use the stackoverflow api (I have seen usecases but the are more or less only used for SEO and SERPS/Index Spamming in google).

Thanks very much!!
Markus

Answer (score 4):

[Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) is an official site where users post and discuss apps, libraries and scripts that use the Stack Exchange API. Most of the interesting uses will be posted there. You may want to start with [the highest-voted applications on the site](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app?sort=votes).

Personally, I find Mac application [Newt](https://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-os-x) very useful. It notifies me of new questions with tags I'm interested in, as well as messages in my global inbox.